# How is ASP.net MVC Request handled?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Could you please help me in understanding how a Request is handled by Asp.Net/ASP.Net MVC Engines? I understand there is Http Handler somewhere in the end of pipeline but I could not see it in Web.config.

Where is MVCHandler being registered and how a request is identified to be handled by MVC Handler?

Thanks A Lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link with a detailed answer:

http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/gopalk/archive/2009/01/20/how-does-asp-net-mvc-work.aspx

it comes down to the new routing http module being added in the webconfig

```
<add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing,
 Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

In the global.asax the routes are mapped towards the right controller

Answer (score 0):

This article by Stephen Walther has a really great description of this process:
http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/03/18/asp-net-mvc-in-depth-the-life-of-an-asp-net-mvc-request.aspx

It's a little old, but nothing has really changed since then.